# JSF Component Tree manipualtion equivalent in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, jsf

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent to the component tree manipulation JSF offers applicable to angular.
With JSF I can use several listeners i.e. to inspect and manipulate the component before rendering to add or remove components, set attributes or simply do some logging.
Is there any mechanism that does the same for angular?

I did some research and found hook-like interfaces that can be implemented by angular components but it seems like this has to be done by "the original developer" mainly. I'm searching for external mechanism I can use, when implementing my own software to alter and extend the behaviour of the used components.